# Foursquare photos/add Venue php

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to upload a photo to a venue on foursquare.

This my code :

```
$image = "/assets/uploads/image/test.jpg";

$fields = json_encode(array("photo" => "@".$image));

$url = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/photos/add?oauth_token=<my-oauth-token>&v=20160609&venueId=<my-venue-id>";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20000);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, file_get_contents($s));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: image/jpeg"));

$response = curl_exec($ch);

echo $response; exit;
```

and response

```
{"meta":{"code":400,"errorType":"other","errorDetail":"Missing file upload","requestId":"57d6abf3498e0eb7f4639fa1"},"notifications":[{"type":"notificationTray","item":{"unreadCount":12}}],"response":{}}
```

Obviously I added the customs token and venue id. 
I tried to add a tip via curl, no problem.
I use codeigniter and php5.4

More info on foursquare API
https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/photos/add

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Check again with `$image = FCPATH . "/assets/uploads/image/test.jpg";`

Comment: did not work, same response.